# Random Number in form of QR Code Generator using Laravel or

Tags: php, laravel, random, numbers, qr-code

I AM looking FOR qR CODE Genenrator when Some One Visit the  Website and Click on Button called  "Generate Code" that Should Generate the Qrcode . Every time New Code.

Comment: Try to use Github to find code that does this: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=qr+code

Answer (score 0):

Okay this should be easy.

```
//First we generate a random number
$number = rand(1,1000);
//we prepare the google charts api
$url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chld=L|0&chl=" . $number;
//echo the qr code
echo "<img src='$url'>";
```

Now you just have to make a ajax request to get the qr code on your page without refreshing.

Comment: Possible for everything, its just normal PHP,